# Polling the google cloud operation using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-cloud-platform

I am using the python code that triggers the rolling update. Is there a polling method through which I can monitor the completion of the patching of all instances? Based on result I need to make another API request.

**Code snippet**

```
request = service.regionInstanceGroupManagers().patch(project=project, region=region, instanceGroupManager=instance_group_manager, body=instance_group_manager_body)
response = request.execute()
```

**Response**

```
{'id': '8587452091206150264',
 'insertTime': '2021-05-23T10:53:27.034-07:00',
 'kind': 'compute#operation',
 'name': 'operation-1621792405532-5c302f83b2df7-6e3912e5-051729ea',
 'operationType': 'patch',
 'progress': 0,
 'region': 'https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/lab-310807/regions/us-central1',
 'selfLink': 'https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/lab-310807/regions/us-central1/operations/operation-1621792405532-5c302f83b2df7-6e3912e5-051729ea',
 'startTime': '2021-05-23T10:53:27.046-07:00',
 'status': 'RUNNING',
 'targetId': '566188121433019459',
 'targetLink': 'https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/lab-310807/regions/us-central1/instanceGroupManagers/mcloudweb-mig',
 'user': 'jkn@gmail.com'}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two steps:

1. Poll status using:

`result=service.regionInstanceGroupManagers().get(project=project, region=region, instanceGroupManager=instance_group_manager)` until `result['status'] == 'DONE'`

2. Separately verify the status of the individual instances with the `listmanagedinstances()` method.